# Directory to store .whl for pip install?

Tags: python, windows, pypi

Where do I put the .whl file I am trying to install with pip?
I tried my script directory and got  a file does not exist error with powershell.

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried giving full path to the .whl file?

Comment: What do you mean, "install with pypi"? PyPI is not something you install with, it's an online package repo. Do you mean "install with pip"? And normally pip downloads from PyPI for you, you don't download the whl yourself.

Comment: Yes, that is what i meant. And I did download the whl myself from a windows binary page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should give full path of the .whl file , or in powershell move to that directory where .whl file is located.